# Spring integration UDP server does not listen

Tags: java, spring, udp, spring-integration

I am using this very simple configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-ip="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip/spring-integration-ip.xsd">

  <int:channel id="sendUdp"/>

  <int-ip:udp-outbound-channel-adapter id="udpOut" host="localhost" port="11111"
                                   multicast="false" check-length="true"
                                   channel="sendUdp" acknowledge="true"
                                   ack-host="localhost" ack-port="12312"
                                   ack-timeout="5000"/>

  <int-ip:udp-inbound-channel-adapter id="udpIn" port="11111" receive-buffer-size="500"
                                  multicast="false" check-length="true"
                                  channel="receiveUdp"/>

  <int:service-activator id="updHandler" input-channel="receiveUdp" ref="listener"/>

</beans>
```

But when I try to telnet localhost 11111  it say it can not connect to it. Can someone please help about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telnet uses TCP not UDP. Try netcat.